# Storing multiple image in one field django rest framework

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

Is it possible to insert many image in one field of same table. For example one user created a profile and that user have to post some pictures in one field. Most user use another table for store image. Need your help

Comment: The first comment of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52903232/8424752)
might help you!

Comment: this will not work. I already did that. Thank for your help

Answer (score 1):

you have to create  different model for that task. Or may be you have to declare array field. I think array field won't work to solve your problem

Comment: I know this won't work for this case. Thanks for your help