# django api how upload multiple images

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I tried many times, but I just register the last one

im my model

```
class PropertyImage(models.Model):
    property = models.ForeignKey(Property, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    images = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.images)
```

serializer

```
class PropertyImageSerializers (serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PropertyImage
        #fields =('name','')
        fields = '__all__'
```

my class view handler the post request, I tried to user method FOR to loop all images and save

view

```
        def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        property_id = request.data['property']
        form_data = {}

        for images in request.FILES.getlist('images'):

            form_data['property']= property_id
            form_data['images']=images

            print(form_data)

            serializer = PropertyImageSerializers(data=form_data)

            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

the for not give me the loop, does't matter how many images I send

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I get this error message: AttributeError: 'PropertyImageSerializers'
> object has no attribute 'property' but im my model you can see I have
> the property

`property` is not an attribute of the `PropertyImageSerializers` class, that's why `AttributeError`

I think you will find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53035559/6510856)

Update:

You can do it like this

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    property_id = request.data['property']
    form_data = {}
    form_data['property']= property_id
    success = True
    response = []
    for images in request.FILES.getlist('images'):
        form_data['images']=images
        print(form_data)
        serializer = PropertyImageSerializers(data=form_data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            response.append(serializer.data)
        else:
            success = False
    if success:
        return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(response,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: I change I little, the for not works I can send many images but I not get loop

Comment: @JúniorOaks the way you did it, the post function may return a response just after the first iteration, which is not the desired behavior, right?  you should return a response after successfully processing all images.

Comment: thanks @md nasfis khan, you right, and I did not append value to the list with the new image, thanks, is running a 100%