# how to post multiple images together in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to create a post request with multiple images in django.

I tried creating a different model for images and connected it to my 'vehicle' model using OnetoOneField, but it only allows to post 1 image at a time.(this method is shown below)

I also tried to get multiple images as a comma-separated string but when I post my images as a list of binary images it shows 'invalid type' error.

I just need to create an API for posting multiple images in one go.

Here is my model.py file -

```
class VehicleImage(models.Model):
    image_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="media")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.vehicle.auction_title

class Vehicle(models.Model):
    auction_title = models.TextField()
    vehicle_images = models.ManyToManyField(VehicleImage, blank=True)
    vehicle_images_list = models.TextField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.auction_title
```

Serializer.py files -

```
class VehicleImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = VehicleImage
        fields = "__all__"

class VehicleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    vehicle_images = VehicleImageSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Vehicle
        fields = "__all__"

    def create(self, validated_data):
        images_data = validated_data['vehicle_images_list']
        vehicle = Vehicle.objects.create(**validated_data)
        if images_data!="":
            for data in images_data.split(','):
                image = VehicleImage.objects.get(image_id=data)
                vehicle.vehicle_images.add(image)
        return vehicle
```

Views.py file

```
class add_vehicle(ListCreateAPIView):        
    queryset = Vehicle.objects.all().order_by('-vehicle_id')
    serializer_class = VehicleSerializer
    pagination_class = CustomPagination

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        # creating the Vehicle
        vehicle_serializer = VehicleSerializer(data=request.data)
        if vehicle_serializer.is_valid():
            vehicle_serializer.save()
            return Response({
                "response":{"vehicle_id":vehicle_serializer.data['vehicle_id']},
                "status_code":200}, status = status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response({
                "response":vehicle_serializer.errors,
                "status_code":400}, status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class add_images(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = VehicleImage.objects.all()
    serializer_class = VehicleImageSerializer
    pagination_class = CustomPagination

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        image_serializer = VehicleImageSerializer(data=request.data)
        if image_serializer.is_valid():
            image_serializer.save()
            return Response({
                "response":image_serializer.data,
                "status_code":200}, status = status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response({
                "response":image_serializer.errors,
                "status_code":400}, status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**Using this method i first add image one by one using 'add_images' class and then give a list of image ids while creating the vehicle. Is there any way to add all the images in one go?**

Comment: I think there is no way to upload multiple images directly using DRF. You might need to iterate images in ```view.py```, for more in details visit https://stackoverflow.com/a/53035559/16785359

Comment: I tried a similar approach as shown in this link. It works with postman, but when I used it with angular it doesn't work because I could not get a list of binary image data. It just shows a list - [<object>,<object>,<object>,.....]

Comment: I am sure, It has an issue with angular not with backend. You should fix the Form or API on frontend.

Answer (score 0):

To Make a post of multiple images to your database first you need to create separate image models for your Vehicles like so:
Model.py

```
class Vehicle(models.Model):
    auction_title = models.TextField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.auction_title

class VehicleImage(models.Model):
    vechicle  = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="media")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.vehicle.auction_title
```

Then you link the two models together in your admin.py with stackedInline, Like So:

```
class VehicleImagesAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
       model = VehicleImage

class VehicleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      # The field your want to display 
      list_display  = ['auction_title','date_created']
      # Here you link the models together 
      inlines = [VehicleImagesAdmin]
```

Now you would need to create a form to handle the multiple uploads

```
class VehicleImagesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = VehicleImage
        fields = ['image']
        widget = forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple':True})
```

We then focus on creating a view to handle post request process on multiple images, mind you i am going to write a function basedview to keep it simple, it's much of the same convention or wisdom with  classbase view so you can as will work around it with your own wisdom. but this works perfectly.

```
def upload_vehicle_images(request):
    form = VehicleImagesForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    files = requests.FILES.getlist['image']
    auction_title = request.POST['auction_title']
    description = request.POST['descritpion']
    vehicle = Vehicle(auction_title=auction_title,description=description)
    vehicle.save()
    # You would have to make some iterations through the list images inorder to post 
    # them to your database
    if form.is_valid:
       for file in files:
           vehicle_image_data = VehicleImage(vehicle=vehicle, image=file)
           vehicle_image_data.save() 
    return redirect(# redirect to anywhere you)
```

HTML Template to post mulple images

```
 <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
<textarea class=""name="auction_title" id="id_auction_title"></textarea>
  <textarea class="" name="description" id="id_description"></textarea>
   <input  type="file" name="image"  id="id_image" multiple accept="image/*" >
 <button  type="submit">Post</button> 
</form>
```

Or you can just use the form when you add it to the context

```
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 {% csrf_token %}
 {% form %}
 <button  type="submit">Post</button> 
</form>
```

Comment: Can i do it without using forms? I just need to create an API and provide it to the frontend team.

Comment: Yes that's what i did with the HTML that's if you don't want to use form. doing something like this <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
<textarea class=""name="auction_title" id="id_auction_title"></textarea>
  <textarea class="" name="description" id="id_description"></textarea>
   <input  type="file" name="image"  id="id_image" multiple accept="image/*" >
 <button  type="submit">Post</button> 
</form>